# How do I know when rosbag finished? (by code - without looking at the terminal)

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm writing a node to convert from a rosbag to a .mat file using matlab's api for this. I am subscribing to the topics contained in the rosbag and via a callback function I can read the respective topic only when there is new data. The issue might be that I need to know when the rosbag ended so I can close the .mat file. Is there any way to know when the rosbag finished? I was not able to find any topic for example that might tell me the status of the rosbag.

Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233011/how-do-i-know-when-rosbag-finished?-(by-code---without-looking-at-the-terminal)/) by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2016-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd say it is easier to use the [rosbag API](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/rosbag/Code%20API) for the conversion instead of playing a rosbag, subcribing to the topic and writing it to a .mat file...

This would acutally solve your question because you are reading the rosbag directly and don't have to start it on the command line.

There is also a [cookbook](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook) with several examploes.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-04-27**:
That's exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot for the answer.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2016-04-27**:
@Ariel, please accept the answer instead of closing the question. Thanks!

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-04-27**:
Now its done

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-04-27**:
One more thing....the cookbok shows how I can access data from that topic. For example, I have this: `nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr odometry = m.instantiate<nav_msgs::Odometry>();` and I can access odometry->pose.pose.position.x. Continued...

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-04-27**:
How can I push_back the entire topic to an How can I push_back the entire topic to std::vector<nav_msgs::Odometry> ? I could populate nav_msgs::Odometry odometryTmp with the each value from the topic and the push_back(odometryTmp), but looks kind of ugly. Is there a better way?